# mongoDB updateOne not updating document

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, nestjs

I need to remove some references to objects in each files section (section1, section2, section3, others).

**Document example:**

```
{
  "_id": "64a3268474aa29e72b40c521",
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "",
  "files": {
    "section1": [
      {
        "$oid": "64e617006e14fecb803b8bb3"
      },
      {
        "$oid": "64e5fba8742cefedd2897e9e"
      }
    ],
    "section2": [
      {
         "$oid": "64e5fba8742cefedd2897e98"
      }
    ],
    "section3": [],
    "others": []
  }
}
```

The IDs of the objects to be deleted are stored in an array `filesToDeleteIds`, each element of the array is responsible for a separate section.

**Example array with IDs to be removed from the document:**

```
`[
  ["64e5fba8742cefedd2897e9a", "64e5fba8742cefedd2897e9e"],
  ["64e5fba8742cefedd2897e98"],
  [],
  []
]`
```

**I do it like this:**

```
await this.myModel.updateOne(
      { _id: id },
      { $pull: {
        'files.section1': { _id: { $in: filesToDeleteIds[0] }},
        'files.section2': { _id: { $in: filesToDeleteIds[1] }},
        'files.section3': { _id: { $in: filesToDeleteIds[2] }},
        'files.others': { _id: { $in: filesToDeleteIds[3] }},
      }},
)
```

But it doesn't work, there are no errors.
The `updateOne` function return this:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

Comment: need to convert each `filesToDeleteIds[n]` to type ObjectID. use a `map` and convert to object id

Comment: Already tried, didn't work

Comment: Why do you think it didn't work? `modifiedCount: 1` says it did work...

Comment: Because nothing changes in the database. Is there any way to see what exactly has changed?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7aEwK7zRhOw is what i meant.

Comment: Oh yes, it worked. Thanks a lot. It was just necessary to remove _id from each section in updateOne function

Answer (score 0):

The `Model.updateOne()` return object you get can often be undesirable if you need to see the changes immediately without making another database request.

I can see you have a solution already but if you wanted to get the document returned after you make the changes then you can use the `{new:true}` option with `Model.findByIdAndUpdate()` like so:

```
// Convert your String Ids to ObjectIds
for(const f of filesToDeleteIds){
   f.forEach((e, i) => {
      f[i] = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(e);
   })
}

// Now do the update with the {new:true} option set
await this.myModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
   id,
   {
      $pull: {
         'files.section1': {$in: filesToDeleteIds[0]},
         'files.section2': {$in: filesToDeleteIds[1]},
         'files.section3': {$in: filesToDeleteIds[2]},
         'files.others': {$in: filesToDeleteIds[3]},
      }
   },
   { new : true }
);
```